# Django CAS and TGT(Ticket Granting Tickets) and service ticket validation

Tags: python, django, cas

I'm using CAS to provide authentication for a number of secure services in my stack. The authentication front-end is implemented using Django 1.6 and the django-cas module. However, I'm reading around and I don't seem to get information on how django-cas handles Ticket Granting Tickets and also validation of service tickets.

Does anyone know how the aspects mentioned are handled by django-cas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out django-cas handles TGT using django sessions. However, for validation of the service ticket, you have to manually make a validation request including the ST(service ticket) granted after login and the service being accessed.